# How to determine if an image is well saturated?

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to implement auto saturation tool for images, I am trying to calculate global saturation of the image and determine how much saturation boost is needed for the image. How can i calculate the global saturation?

Comment: This is about RGB images I presume? You can start by converting to a different colorspace, namely [Hue Saturation Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the question, if all you care about is saturation boost this is the most simple algorithm:

1. Find the pixel with the maximum saturation in the image.
2. Determine how much you can scale the saturation it before it becomes 100% saturated and clips. (This is the maximum you can boost the saturation before you start to lose data)
3. Apply saturation scaling amount of less than the amount you just determined.

An image may be well saturated if it is not over saturated and not under saturated...
Imagine a close up shot of a red rose. If it was totally saturated the whole image would just be red. So an over saturated image may have a high percentage of pixels having the same, or very close, color. If our red rose close up shot was under saturated it may not contain any pixels that are 100% red and will appear to be pink instead of red. So if an image has no pixels that are close to full saturation it may be under saturated.

Some other things to consider:

Be aware that saturation may have a perceptual aspect to it... 
A red square on a black background may appear more saturated than a red square on a white background.

You may need multiple passes. Break up the image into subject and background and apply the saturation function to each separately.

Too much saturation can make things look flat. Too little saturation can make things look dead.

Also the image may already be too saturated... in that case reduce the saturation of the background and the subject will appear more saturated.

As far as the saturation function try converting to HSL colorspace; you can scale the S component to adjust the saturation; than convert back to RGB if that was your original color space. Build a histogram from the color data. You will see that many images share a similar histogram. Based on the histogram scenario you can choose the appropriate saturation scale factor.